# Editing Table View Data from seperate Detail View Controller

Tags: swift

I was wondering what is the best way to edit data in a table view from a detail view? I have a global array I am using to populate the table view. Along with a global struct. I understand how to list data on table view, just do not understand how to edit data once it has been put in array.

Comment: Can you be more specific or add a code snippet of what you're trying to edit? Are you trying to edit the values within the array and change the appearance of the table? Or edit the appearance of the table? More information would be helpful

Comment: Edit the array, I will upload code snippet next time I am at my computer:) thanks!